# How do I use a value from another class that is changed via the main method?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a State Machine that runs on it's own. So you start it and values change and if the value gets below or above a certain level it changes State. But I'm stuck.

This is the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BankRobber br = new BankRobber(stR, 0, 100, 200);
    Cop cop = new Cop(stC, 0);
        br.changeRobberState();
        br.robberStats();
        br.checkRobberState();
        cop.changeCopState();
        cop.copStats();
        cop.checkCopState();
        }
}
```

And here is an example as to how robberStats() works:

```
 if (st == robberState.ROBBINGBANK) {
 money += 1000;
 distanceToCop -= 20;
 energy -= 8;
}
```

The BankRobber object has three different int values. money, energy and distanceToCop. 
The method that is changing these values is robberStats(). Depending on what state it is in it changes the value.
I want to use the distanceToCop value in the Cop class. But I don't know how to use the distanceToCop value from the BankRobber class in Cop. Can anybody help?

Comment: That will maybe work, but I wouldn't consider it a good advice.

Comment: You obviously need a BankRobber object reference in Cop.

Comment: Create a getter in `BankRobber` and use that value with your `Cop` object? And no, don't use `static` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach will be you will have some sort of `Manager` class which will have reference to both the `Cop` and the `BankRobber` reading their values via *getters* and setting new values via *setters*. As it should run forever you may want to put the behaviour in some sort of (infinite) loop.

```
class Manager {
  private Cop cop;
  private BankRobber robber;

  public void run() {

    while (true /* or something else*/) {
      int distanceToCop = robber.getDistanceToCop();
      cop.updateState(distanceToCop);

      /* Maybe get something from cop now and call updateState on robber */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public static variable distanceToCop in BankRobber class.
Use it in Cop class directly by calling BankRobber.distanceToCop from Cop class method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I fixed it with getter and setter methods. Thanks for the tips